# Changing classes using javascript. (replace method) fontawesome icons

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I want to change the `bars` icon to `times` icon whenever for example when the icon's class is `fa fa-bars`. but there is something wrong with the code but I think the JS code is true and doesn't have any problems. here is the code:

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('#menu');

// Show Navbar
const showNav = () => {
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav');
    nav.classList.toggle('show');
}

menu.addEventListener('click', showNav);

// Menu icon change
 const menuTimes = () => {
    const menuIcon = document.querySelector('.fa-bars');

    if (menuIcon.classList === 'fa fa-bars') {
        menuIcon.classList.replace('fa fa-bars', 'fas fa-times');
    } else if (menuIcon.classList === 'fas fa-times') {
        menuIcon.classList.replace('fas fa-times', 'fa fa-bars');
    }
};

menu.addEventListener('click', menuTimes);

// ------------------------------------------
// I also tried this but nothing worked

//const menuIcon = document.querySelector('.fa-bars');

//if (menuIcon.classList === 'fa fa-bars') {
//  menuIcon.classList.replace('fa fa-bars', 'fas fa-times');
//} else if (menuIcon.classList === 'fas fa-times') {
//  menuIcon.classList.replace('fas fa-times', 'fa fa-bars');
//}
```

```css
.show {
  display: block !important;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Navbar -->
<div id="menu">
    <nav class="nav hidden" id="nav">
        <a href="#" class="show">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="show">About</a>
    </nav>

    <!-- Bars icon -->
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</div>

<!-- Font awsome cdn (SVG) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/js/all.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Font Awesome, if you don't nest SVG tags within their parent, here’s what you need to know:

The library seeks out tags that look like icons:

```
<i class="fas fa-coffee" data-fa-mask="fas fa-circle"></i>
```

They are replaced with a new svg element:

```
<svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-coffee fa-w-20" aria-hidden="true" data-fa-i2svg="" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="coffee" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M192 384h192c53 0 96-43 96-96h32c70.6 0 128-57.4 128-128S582.6 32 512 32H120c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v232c0 53 43 96 96 96zM512 96c35.3 0 64 28.7 64 64s-28.7 64-64 64h-32V96h32zm47.7 384H48.3c-47.6 0-61-64-36-64h583.3c25 0 11.8 64-35.9 64z"></path></svg>
<!-- <i class="fas fa-coffee"></i> -->
```

> Why is this important?
> Since elements are replaced, any bindings to the element will be lost.

Right here you have the full documentation https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/jquery

Since you are not using nest I wrap the `<i>` element for a proper binding

```
<!-- Bars icon -->
    <span id="menu-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </span>
```

Then you can bind the click event to `#menu-icon` element and look for the `svg` element inside, I'm using jQuery which I strongly recommend you to use.

```
// Menu icon change
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    $('#menu-icon').on('click', function () {
      $(this)
        .find('.svg-inline--fa')
        .toggleClass('fa-bars')
        .toggleClass('fa-times');
    });
  });
```

I'll provide a working snippet:

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('#menu');

// Show Navbar
const showNav = () => {
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav');
  nav.classList.toggle('show');
}

menu.addEventListener('click', showNav);

// Menu icon change
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  $('#menu-icon').on('click', function() {
    $(this)
      .find('.svg-inline--fa')
      .toggleClass('fa-bars')
      .toggleClass('fa-times');
  });
});

// ------------------------------------------
// I also tried this but nothing worked

//const menuIcon = document.querySelector('.fa-bars');

//if (menuIcon.classList === 'fa fa-bars') {
//  menuIcon.classList.replace('fa fa-bars', 'fas fa-times');
//} else if (menuIcon.classList === 'fas fa-times') {
//  menuIcon.classList.replace('fas fa-times', 'fa fa-bars');
//}
```

```css
.show {
  display: block !important;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Navbar -->
<div id="menu">
  <nav class="nav hidden" id="nav">
    <a href="#" class="show">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="show">About</a>
  </nav>

  <!-- Bars icon -->
  <span id="menu-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </span>
</div>

<!-- Font awsome cdn (SVG) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/js/all.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`menuIcon.classList` retrieves a DOMTokenList, similiar to an array.

[Check MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

> A DOMTokenList representing the contents of the element's class
> attribute. If the class attribute is not set or empty, it returns an
> empty DOMTokenList, i.e. a DOMTokenList with the length property equal
> to 0.

If you want to access the class as a string, use `menuIcon.classList.value`. It should return `"fa fa-bars"`.

***Edit:***

using .value, you are going to be able to test `menuIcon.classList.value === "fa fa-bars"` etc.